# Finding value in diophantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

A professor returned to his home  USA after attending a conference in paris and london. He have some money left in euros and pounds sterling. he want to traded both of them into dollars. he received 117.98 dollars with the exchange rate of 1 euro is 11.1 dollars and 1 pound is 1.69 dollars. how nominal euro and pound that he exchanged?
In this diophantine equation i can write it euros is x, pounds is y so 
$11.1x+1.69y=117.98$
$1110x+169y=11798$
$gcd(1110,169)=1$

$1|11798$ is true then i find $(x',y')$
$1=-44(1110)+289(169)$
$11798=-519112(1110)+3409622(169)$

If we talk about money so $x>=0$ and $y>=0$

$x=-519112+169n$
$x>=0$
$-519112+169n>=0$
$n>=3071.6$
So i find $n={3072,3073,...}$
Then for y
$y=3409622-1110n$
$y>=0$

With same method like x i find that 
$n={...,3070,3071}$

What i got from this is that x and y not both positive. Is that possible?

Comment: I think you have 1110 where you should have 111.

Comment: All of equation is multiple by 100, so 11.1x100 is 1110 not 111

Comment: When was a Euro ever worth $11.1$ USD! $1.11$ seems better.

Comment: I just seeing the question

Comment: But i think its true, when a euro is 11,1 usd? I will check it

Comment: I note that after my comment above, OP edited the question, changing 1.11 to 11.1

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, use euro to dollars rate of $1.11$

Clear the cents to give $111x+169y=11798$

Solve, either with the method shown in your question, or just cheat with
http://planetcalc.com/3303/

Either way,

$$x=790466+169k$$

$$y=-519112-111k$$

Clearly, $y>0$, so calculate $-519112/111=-4676.68$

Try $k=-4677$ to give $x=53,y=35$

Now $k=-4678$ and smaller makes $x$ negative.

Also, $k=-4676$ and larger makes $y$ negative, so there is just one answer.

**$53$ euro, $35$ pounds**

Answer (score 0):

By applying the Euclidean division to the equation $111x+169y=11768$, we arrive at the solution:

$x=71+169t$

$y=23-111t$

where  t is a parameter.

Taking between the infinite solutions that minimum, that is, the one with $t=0$ , we get

$x=71$ and $y=23$.